# Correct way to scale a project and database over time

Tags: database-design, architecture, system, upgrade

I am working on a clients project for some time now. The technology stack comprises of `laravel8` backend, `MariaDB` as data storage, and `Quasar` (vue based) as a front end that communicates through `REST API`. This setup has served them quite well for some time and now they are planning to expand their customer base which means

1. More concurrent Users
2. More data being generated
3. Database becoming bloated

I am interested in knowing what is the right way to scale a system and am interested in the following questions

1. Since the database is relational, let's say they have a student for which they placed the order and 3 years from now the student left and they decide to delete the student. How do you handle this situation to prevent old data crashing? Don't physically delete from storage and just hide?
2. Some articles suggest that introduce secondary or even tertiary databases and keep migrating old un-used data to those while keeping the active database lightweight. Is this a being a good approach?
3. What resources can I explore to have a better understanding to learn the process of scaling the systems.
4. What is the right way to implement the constant property changing in databases like this. For example `John Doe` is in 6th grade. He has an exam record, library record, fee record etc. Since this was relational and we change the child's data as he goes in different grades say 8th and someone try to get his library records when he was in grade 6, being relational data it's going to show the updated grade. They currently have a view table that has `student_id`, `grade_id`, `join_date`, `leave_date`, and `leave_reason`

Thanks

Comment: 1) You can "delete" a row by setting a flag.  This is good for maintaining a history while keeping the number of active rows constant.  Sometimes, a separate history table is better.  2) I'd use history tables and not multiple databases and database engines.  3) Make sure your database is fully normalized.  Upgrade your database server as needed.  4)   Again, maintain proper history tables.  Save everything you need to maintain John Doe's 6th grade records.

Comment: Dude, why not post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I second what Gilbert said.

Re #2 - I agree with Gilbert.  That said, one approach that can be useful is to copy read-only data into a data store that is geared towards satisfying high-volume reads, on the basis that reads are more common than writes.

As to what form the read-only data store takes - there's many options.  One thing to do, which may help you deal with some of your other challenges, is to conduct a performance and capacity planning exercise:

1. Form a rough list of the main data objects/record types that are significant, e.g. customers, orders, products.
2. For each: count how many you have, and the estimated a growth rate for them (e.g. per year or month).
3. Calculate how much growth you have over a given period - what are the totals you need to support.

Then:

1. Do some research into your technology choices and understand what volumes they support.  How does the nature of their infrastructure affect those advertised limits?
2. Do the same into your hosting / infrastructure - how is that implemented and what can it support?  What can it be easily extended to support before you need to re-architect?
3. Understand to what extent your infrastructure matches guidance set out by your technology's vendors.

In summary you want to understand how much capacity you need, how much the systems you have can support.  It might be they can support it, provided your infrastructure is suitable.

Big note: throwing infrastructure at a bad design is not the right approach.  But understanding what your actual likely limits are is generally a good idea - "hope is not a strategy" and all that.